# Вероятность использования метода в Java

Tags: java

Есть цикл, в котором находятся 4 метода. Я хочу понять, как сделать, чтобы методы исполнялись не каждый шаг цикла, а с вероятностью:

- первый: 60%
- второй: 10%
- третий: 15%
- четвертый: 15%

Есть ли какой то специальный метод? Я не могу понять логику.

Comment: генерируете случайное число от 0 до 100 (или от 0 до 1) и в зависимости от него вызываете нужный метод. Т.е. второй метод будет вызываться если число от 0 до 10, третий - от 10 до 25, четвертый - от 25 до 40, а первый метод - от 40 до 100.

Comment: Я понял твою логику) хороший вариант. Сделать еще методы boolean и true при нужном значении, чтобы наверняка. Ты напиши свой ответ в ответы, а не комментарии, я до вечера еще послушаю чьи нибудь варианты, и если что поставлю тебе правильный ответ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простейшее решение, основанное на стандартном генераторе случайных чисел:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int b = rnd .nextInt(100);

if (b < 60)
    method1();    // 60%
else if (b < 70)
    method2();    // 10%
else if (b < 85)
    method3();    // 15%
else
    method4();    // 15%
```

Comment: да)) 
то что нужно :) спасибо))